# Does this structure have a grammatical name?

Tags: grammar, phrases, structure

> Use it, when necessary
>
> Take, when needed
>
> Write, when told.

So, sentences like this have something omitted. In the first one, it’s `..., when it’s necessary.` or the second one has two of them being `Take it, when it’s needed.`. The third one can be written as `Write, when you’re told.`.

So, what is this structure called? Does this have a specific name? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first one seems different from the other two.  The second and third can be understood as a participle modifier. The first one is odd,  probably ellipsis of the subject and verb leaving a reduced clause.  @BillJ can probably give full details.

Comment: You see this type of command  on medicine bottles -- "Take with food." or "Take as needed for pain." They omit a reference to the object, because the directions obviously refer to the medicine. They omit the subject, "You", because commands usually do this.

Comment: @JamesK Hi there. I see. So, I decided to use the first one in a sentence like this: `I didn’t say I don’t use it. I use it when necessary.`. Does this sound ambiguous when used like this?

Comment: @FeliniusRex Hi there. So, you mean this can mostly be possible in commands and not in sentences? Like, saying `I take the pills when necessary.` doesn’t seem right?

Comment: @NUMERICALUDD A command is a kind of sentence. Sure, you can say, "I take the pills when necessary." It's completely normal and natural English. "Hey Harry, you take those pills all the time, don't you?" "No. I only take the pills when necessary."

Comment: @FeliniusRex Great! These days I’m doubting myself so much about the things I know . Thank you so much for your replies and time.